# 18.04 Server, Ethernet Interface seen w/ lspci, but missing from lshw -C network

Tags: networking, drivers, server, ethernet

we've just changed the case at an old pc (ubuntu 18.04 - no GUI) we use for testing at work, resulting in losing access to the network - ping 8.8.8.8, returns:

```
"connect: Network is unreachable"
```

What we did to troubleshoot this:
1. Fixed the datetime -> reboot
2. Changed the dhcp4 to "True" (and then "Yes")
3. sudo netplan --debug generate
4. sudo netplan --debug apply

The latter returns:

```
"NetworkManager: definition enp0s7 is not for us (backend 1)".
```

ifconfig -a:

```
docker0: flags=[...]

enp0s7: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>   mtu 1500
        ether 00:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  txqueuelen 1000   (Ethernet)
        [...]
lo: flags=73 [...]
```

lspci result:

```
00:07.0 Bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet (rev a2)
        Kernel driver in user: forcedeth
        Kernel modules: forcedeth
```

Thank you in advance for any help/insight/source to figure out what happened!

**EDIT**

@heynnema Thank you so much for your promptness to help! Please find below the results:

01-network-card.yaml (the latest attempt to let DHCP open & get a dynamic IP):

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
            enp0s7:
                    dhcp4: yes
```

01-network-card.yaml.save

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
            enp0s7:
                    dhcp4: no
                    addresses: [192.168.1.97/24]
                    gateway4: 192.168.1.1
                    nameservers:
                            addresses: [8.8.4.4,8.8.8.8]
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
physical id: 1
logical name: docker0
serial: 02:42:72:32:11:63
capabilities: ethernet physical
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces (It seems that it's not even installed, due to `netplan`)

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you very much for your prompt reply, I've just edited my question with the info you need!

Comment: Show me `sudo lshw -class bridge`.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your ethernet cabling. You should be using cat 5e or cat 6 cables.

Assuming that `sudo lshw -class bridge` shows that enp0s7 is your ethernet card...

**.yaml file**

Netplan is very fussy about .yaml formatting. Your `/etc/netplan/01-network-card.yaml` should look like (keep spacing, and no tabs):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s7:
      dhcp4: true
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

---

**Nvidia driver**

The `NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet` appears to be a difficult card to get working.

From [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1003297) bug report, we get this snippet to modify the forcedeth driver...

enter these two commands in a terminal:

```
echo "options forcedeth msi=0 msix=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/forcedeth_options.conf
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

then reboot your machine

Comment: Already tried the 1st approach with the dhcp enabled (check the 1st yaml file). I'll try your solution on the Nvidia driver though asap, thanks!

Comment: @Lopofsky my .yaml is different than yours, as it follows the particularly fussy netplan .yaml formatting rules. Change your .yaml. Report back on both.

Comment: @Lopofsky status please...

Comment: @Lopofsky Please give me feedback on which specific item in my answer resolved the problem. Thanks!